# Mongodb document insertion order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb collection for tracking user audit data. So essentially this will be many millions of documents.

Audits are tracked by loginID (user) and their activities on items. example: userA modified 'item#13' on date/time.

Case: I need to query with filters based on user and item. That's Simple. This returns many thousands of documents per item. I need to list them by latest date/time (descending order).

Problem: How can I insert new documents to the top of the stack? (like a capped collection) or Is it possible to find records from the bottom of the stack? (reverse order). I do NOT like the idea of find and sorting because when dealing with thousand and millions of documents sorting is a bottleneck.

Any solutions?

Stack: mongodb, node.js, mongoose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> the top of the stack?

you're implying there is a stack, but there isn't - there's a tree, or more precisely, a B-Tree.

> I do NOT like the idea of find and sorting

So you want to sort without sorting? That doesn't seem to make much sense. Stacks are essentially in-memory data structures, they don't work well on disks because they require huge contiguous blocks (in fact, huge stacks don't even work well in memory, and growing stacks requires copying the entire data set, that would hardly work

> sorting is a bottleneck

It shouldn't be, at least not for data that is stored closely together (data locality). Sorting is an O(m log n) operation, and since the `_id` field already encodes a timestamp, you already have a field that you can sort on. `m` is relatively small, so I don't see the problem here. Have you even tried that? With MongoDB 3.0, index intersectioning has become more powerful, you might not even need `_id` in the compound index.

On my machine, getting the top items from a large collection, filtered by an index takes 1ms `("executionTimeMillis" : 1)` if the data is in RAM. The sheer network overhead will be in the same league, even on localhost. I created the data with a simple [network creation tool](https://github.com/cmenge/mongo-network) I built and queried it from the mongo console.

Comment: The question @user3658423 asked makes a lot of sense, actually. And it does not matter if you have a list or a tree backing your data. In the case of a list, finding the head and/or the tail is O(1). In the case of a tree, it's O(log2 n), given that you have an index which gives you the insertion order. So, the question is actually: Is there an index out of the box which delivers data in the same order it was inserted?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. My solution is to create another additional collection which maintain top 10 records. The good point is that you can query quickly. The bad point is you need update additional collection.

I found [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/) which inspired me. I implemented my solution with ruby + mongoid.

My solution:

collection definition

```
class TrainingTopRecord
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :training_records, :type=>Array

  belongs_to :training

  index({training_id: 1}, {unique: true, drop_dups: true})
end
```

maintain process.

```
if t.training_top_records == nil
  training_top_records = TrainingTopRecord.create! training_id: t.id
else
  training_top_records = t.training_top_records
end
training_top_records.training_records = [] if training_top_records.training_records == nil
top_10_records = training_top_records.training_records
top_10_records.push({
  'id' => r.id,
  'return' => r.return
})
top_10_records.sort_by! {|record| -record['return']}
#limit training_records' size to 10
top_10_records.slice! 10, top_10_records.length - 10
training_top_records.save
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb's [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) is structured in a way that has natural ordering.
This means the last inserted item is fetched last.

You can override that by using: `db.collectionName.find().sort({ $natural: -1 })` during a fetch.

Filters can then follow.

You will not need to create any additional indices since this works on `_id`, which is indexed by default.

This is possibly the only efficient way you can achieve what you want.